# VLA works on gcc-4.9.2 but not on gcc-6.2.0

Tags: c, variable-length-array

A very simple code to test VLA on `gcc` works fine on gcc-4.2.9 (Raspbian), but not on gcc-6.2.0 (Ubuntu). I am surprised. Though it compile without error, the output is not proper.

#### Code:

```
    int len, i;
    int test[len];

    scanf("%d",&len);
    for(i=0;i<=len;i++){
            test[i]=i*i;
            printf("%d\t",test[i]);}

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
```

#### Argument:

```
8
```

#### Output:

With 4.2.9 (Raspbian),

```
0       1       4       9       16      25      36      49      64
```

With 6.2.0 (Ubuntu),

```
0       1       4       9       16      1
```

It doesn't even reach to the count of 8. I am surprised. The same code works if I hard code the value of `len`.

```
0       1       4       9       16      25      36      49      64
```

Any idea about what is possibly going wrong?

Comment: This isn't really a Unix & Linux question.  This sort of faulty C programming can be done on any operating system.  (-:

Comment: Is this an interview question - tell us what is wrong with this program? An array declared as `int test[len]` has valid indices 0 ... len-1 so you are overunning the end of the array.

Comment: `len` isn't initialized before VLA is defined.

Answer (score 2):

```
int len, i;
int test[len];
```

You're doing `test[len]`, but at this point `len` hasn't been initialized. Reading from an uninitialized variable has undefined behavior.

To fix this, initialize `len` before using it:

```
if (scanf("%d",&len) != 1) {
    // handle error
}
int test[len];
```

And in the rest of your code, use `i<len` instead of `i<=len` because otherwise you'd access `len+1` elements where only `len` exist.